# Return HTML Content when given URL using JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have obtained a URL in a variable. Using the url I would like to get a particular content from that HTML page.

The URL is http://www.linkedin.com/profile/view?id=1112465

From this page I would like to get the current company data using JavaScript.

So please help me with this.

Comment: The only solution involves using some server side code acting as a proxy to fetch the page and pass it on to your javascript.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you don't work for linked in, here's the simplest answer: you can't.

There are cross-origin limitations that disallow fetching content from a domain other than the one that's requesting it. What's this mean? `abc.com` can't request content from `xyz.com`--at least not without special permission.